# Creating a new Site Application template

Tags: sharepoint-designer, site-template

i am looking to create a new custom site application template and am pretty novice in sharepoint/wiki pages. I am using Sharepoint 365 and right now when you click NEW under site application it brings you to a page that names the site and then the new page is a blank text box you can type in. Is there anyway to click NEW under Site and select a NEW template that you create that fills in pre determined information instead of retyping it for every site? Example, we are looking to create new sites for systems in our organization and each systems is to be documented the same way. We will then want to be able to have each section dynamically populated.[image]